# Pandas apply (with futures) running much slower on df[:1000] than on the entire df

Tags: python, pandas, performance, parallel-processing, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to apply some function to each row in some df and then save the results. I'm prototyping on about 1500 rows but in future I'll need to process ~1m rows so I'd like to break the df down into chunks (say of 1k), processing each individually (and saving results of each chunk to a new file):

```py
def partition(data, partition_size=1000):
  for i in range(0, len(data), partition_size):
    yield data.iloc[i:i + partition_size]

futures = None
for i, part in partition(df):
  with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
    futures = part.apply(lambda x: executor.submit(process, x), axis=1)
  features = pd.Series(futures.apply(lambda f: f.result())).apply(pd.Series).fillna(0.0)
  features.to_csv(get_output_path(i))
```

Ironically, this runs many times faster:

```py
futures = df.apply(lambda x: executor.submit(process, x), axis=1)
```

despite the fact that it processes 1500 rows twice (rather than processing 2 batches of size 1000 and 500 respectively).

I tried all kinds of remedies to no avail. I thought maybe the issue is with `.iloc` returning a view so I tried to deep copy these before processing. I tried partitioning using `groupby`. I tried sending rows to the pool one by one and flushing at 1000. And a bunch of other ideas that didn't work out - but nothing came anywhere near processing the entire data frame in one go:

```py
futures = None
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
  futures = df.apply(lambda x: executor.submit(process, x), axis=1)
features = pd.Series(futures.apply(lambda f: f.result())).apply(pd.Series).fillna(0.0)
features.to_csv(get_output_path(i))
```

I'm planning to process large datasets on AWS and even though I'm planning to use an instance with 72GB, I estimate the total output to take around >60GB on disk so it's going to be hell to deal with unless I split the results into chunks. I could always process the entire df in-memory and only split at `to_csv` but I don't think 72GB will necessarily cope with such maneuvers and more importantly I'd rather not have my code rely on so much RAM being available in the first place. I should be able to do this at O(1) memory without sacrificing so much performance in terms of speed.

What am I missing?

Comment: From a glance, your `executor.submit` is within row-wise `apply` function for both running for entire or chunks of dataframe.  Whether you do it for entire or chunks, it doesn't look like it speeds up the `apply` function.  Rather, partitioning is adding more steps and loops.  You can try making `process` function to take dataframe instead and call `executor.submit(process, part)`

Comment: right, the whole point is that I process rows in parallels and it's always worked great for me - the problem seems to somehow be related to the partitioning :shrug: maybe I didn't explain that well but basically `df.apply(...); df.apply(...)` takes orders of magnitude less time than `half1.apply(...); half2.apply(...)`. That's what doesn't make any sense

Comment: I see. you tried to measure the time for running twice for the whole dataframe and comparing against the 2 * half?   and the 2 * whole df took less time?  Yeah, that is puzzling.

Putting aside that comparison, yet, applying `executor.submit` per row is making too much jobs, too much overhead and # of execution is bounded by `max_workers`. 
It is likely that the `max_workers` is smaller than what vectorization can take care at 1 time. 

Sorry I am not answering to your question but I would first try to take out `submit` out from the `apply`.

Comment: `ThreadPoolExecutor` only works well as long as the GIL is released  and I doubt this is the case. At least, if your columns contains strings or any pure-Python objects or even Pandas object, then the GIL will prevent any speed up. Did you tried with processes? Processes can be slow too due to IPC but if your computation is intensive compare to the amount of data, then it is fine. To check if the GIL is released, you can simply check the core usage.

Comment: actually I get amazing boosts even with TPE because my task is both I/O and CPU intensive (each row contains a reference to an online resource which is then fetched and processed locally)

Comment: PPE usually complains about being run from a notebook and even setting this aside hasn't really performed any better than TPE for similar tasks before

Comment: ok, this is getting creepy - so I thought whatever if somehow processing entire dfs is faster, I'll just do that. So first I tried writing a csv and reading with `chunksize` - no luck. Then, I tried actually writing individual csvs, reading one by one - still speed reverts to "split speed". this is mad